# How to set C# Property with Linq Statement?

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, properties

0 Project.

I have property

```
public string UserName { get; set; }
```

can i set this property to retrieve user name using linq statement?

```
from u in context.Users
where u.UserID==session["UserID"]
select u.UserName
```

something like this

```
public string UserName { get value; 
set from u in context.Users
    where u.UserID==session["UserID"]
    select u.UserName; }
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Your code doesn't make much sense to me and I think you've got things backwards (code on the `set` rather than the `get`).

Comment: Note that if you are going to code the get in this way, you should probably do something with the set (or remove it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
public string UserName {
    get {
        return (from u in context.Users
                where u.UserID==session["UserID"]
                select u.UserName).SingleOrDefault(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: this `set` clause in the getter is news to me. What is that supposed to do?

Comment: @Icarus: I think John just copied it by mistake.

Comment: Yes i think he only copied it wrong but still would need a return in the get. :)

Comment: @Joey I see, thanks. I thought it was something new in C# 4.5 or something. I was going to run to Barnes and Noble to buy me a book ;)

Answer (score 1):

The get part of your code should look like this if you try to return the UserName

```
get
{
   var result = (from u in context.Users
where u.UserID==session["UserID"]
select u.UserName).FirstOrDefault();
return result;

}
```

Comment: @Joey yes i know i could return it directly, i just wrote it like that so it is easier to understand. Tell me what you want in the set part and i can write you how you could realize it, but i think you don't need a set part if you read the sessions user in the get, so every time you use this property it gets the sessions UserName for you.